# Windows make throws an error when I try to use "if EXIST"

Tags: windows, gnu-make

I am using make version 4.2.1 on windows. I have a very simple make file:

```
some_target:
        if EXIST C:\ echo hi
```

However, when I run the following command:

```
"..\env\build_tools\make\make.exe" -f "make.mk" -j16 some_target
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [make.mk: some_target] Error 2
```

When I run the same recipe line in a regular command prompt it executes perfectly fine and doesn't throw any errors. What is happening here? It's also weird because if I put the source code and makefile in an eclipse project and configure the build correctly, it runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not that mysterious; the answer is in the output you posted here:

```
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This means that the command you told make to run was given to `/usr/bin/sh`, which is a POSIX shell.  But the command you wanted to run:

```
    if EXIST C:\ echo hi
```

is a Windows `cmd.exe` shell command.  That cannot work.  Try starting a Git Bash shell for example and typing the above command into it: you'll get the same error.  If you want your makefile to always use `cmd.exe` as its shell you have to add that to your makefile:

```
SHELL := cmd.exe
```

should do it I think (I don't really do Windows).  The make program was created back in the 1970's on UNIX systems and so it's fundamentally a POSIX program and it prefers to run using POSIX tools; if you don't specify which shell to use then the Windows port will first look for a POSIX shell and if one is found it will use that; if it's not found it will fall back to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. I don't normally use Windows either which is why I noticed that it was using bash but I didn't think much of it.